# R Dplyr - how to make a time series price variation

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been learning R recently and I wanted to create a table of price variation for some products.

For example I have two days of prices for five different products:

```
    library(dplyr)
    df_T0 <- data.frame(brand=c("AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE"),price=c(1,2,3,4,5),time=rep("03/01/2015",5))
    df_T1 <- data.frame(brand=c("AAA","BBB","DDD","EEE","FFF"),price=c(1.5,2.5,4.5,5,7),time=rep("03/02/2015",5))
    df <- rbind(df_T0,df_T1)
```

This results in the following table:

```
        brand price       time
    1    AAA   1.0 03/01/2015
    2    BBB   2.0 03/01/2015
    3    CCC   3.0 03/01/2015
    4    DDD   4.0 03/01/2015
    5    EEE   5.0 03/01/2015
    6    AAA   1.5 03/02/2015
    7    BBB   2.5 03/02/2015
    8    DDD   4.5 03/02/2015
    9    EEE   5.0 03/02/2015
    10   FFF   7.0 03/02/2015
```

I wanted to compare prices between the two dates by using:

```
    df1 <- arrange(df,desc(brand,time))
    df1 %>% mutate(P_yest=lag(price,1,order_by=brand))
```

Which results in:

```
       brand price       time P_yest
    1    FFF   7.0 03/02/2015    5.0
    2    EEE   5.0 03/01/2015    4.5
    3    EEE   5.0 03/02/2015    5.0
    4    DDD   4.0 03/01/2015    3.0
    5    DDD   4.5 03/02/2015    4.0
    6    CCC   3.0 03/01/2015    2.5
    7    BBB   2.0 03/01/2015    1.5
    8    BBB   2.5 03/02/2015    2.0
    9    AAA   1.0 03/01/2015     NA
    10   AAA   1.5 03/02/2015    1.0
```

Only for AAA I got the intended results, for all of the others I got some strange results...

Any hints?

Comment: Something like this: `df1 %>% group_by(brand) %>% mutate(P_yest = lag(price, 1))` ?

Comment: @StevenBeaupré that potentially wouldn't work because of the bug in `dplyr 0.4.1`: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/925. Instead, one has to calculate `lag` manually, e.g. `df %>% group_by(brand) %>% mutate(P_yest=c(NA,price[-length(price)]))`

Comment: @MaratTalipov You're right. I did not check the result before posting.